# I cannot open an image using a canvas and create_image on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a game for the repl.it game jam. I am trying to put an image on a canvas that was created in a different class from the class that the image is being created on. The canvas has successfully displayed text and a button with the image that I need, but `create_image` is not working.

This might be an issue with resolution, but I cannot check that right now, the image is 1920 x 1080 and so is the game.

I've already tried `create_image`.

[Full program](https://repl.it/@NicholasPoslus1/Astrotanks) (including images)

```
class game(Application):
    """Where game elements are to be held"""

    def __init__(self, players, location, sWidth, sHeight, canvas):
        """Initiate variables & start game"""

        #Initiate variables
        self.players = players
        self.location = location
        self.screenWidth = sWidth
        self.screenHeight = sHeight
        self.Canvas1 = canvas

        self.LOCATIONS = Application.LOCATIONS
        self.font = Application.font

        #Gathering Images
        self.map1BG = PhotoImage(file = "polasib.gif")

        #Debugging
        print("Loading Map", self.location\
        , "\nPlayers:", self.players)

        self.createLevel(self.location)

    def createUI(self, players):
        """Creates the UI that all levels will have"""
        self.Canvas1.create_text(self.screenWidth/2, self.screenHeight/16, fill = "white", \
        font = (self.font, self.screenWidth//34), text = self.LOCATIONS[self.location - 1])

    def createLevel(self, location):
        """Creates the elements of the level"""


        if self.location == 1:
            #Polasi b
            print("Creating Polasi b Level")
            self.createUI(self.players) 

            self.Canvas1.create_image(self.screenWidth/2, self.screenHeight/2, image = self.map1BG, \
            anchor = NW)
```

Expectation: I expect the image to load (and that it will require some realignment)

Result: No image appears but everything else added (as a test) works.

Comment: Did you reach `print("Creating Polasi b Level")` and why `self.screenHeight/16` and image position `self.screenHeight/2`, the image got probably  place outside of `self.Canvas1`.

Comment: Yes it does reach `print("Creating Polasi b Level")` dividing the screen height by 16 allows the resolution to be scalable and it allows it to be positioned where I need it to be. I think you are probably right about the image being placed outside of the canvas but I still haven't been able to find a value that works.

Comment: Instead of using `self.screenHeight` use `self.Canvas1.winfo_height()` or use `.create_image(0, 0...` with `anchor='nw'`. [Canvas.create_image-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method)

Comment: Did you assign the instance of `game` to a variable?

Comment: @acw1668 yes I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not save the reference to the instance of `game`, it will be destroyed after exiting `Application.gameScreen()`.  Therefore the reference of the `image` of `create_image` will be lost and no image will be shown.  Try assigning the instance of `game` to an instance variable of `Application`, like below:

```
self.running_game = game(self.players, self.mapChosen, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight, self.Canvas1)
```

Comment: Thank you, you've figured it out!